# wrong number or types of arguments in calling stored proc using jdbc template

Tags: java, oracle, syntax-error, procedure, spring-jdbc

I have a stored procedure like this -

```
procedure         GET_WISLA_REPORT
(
       chkActiveWI varchar default null,
       chkWILastYr varchar default null,
       chkSLAMetPercentage varchar default null,
       chkAvgCompletionTime varchar default null,
       chkActiveWorkTypes varchar default null,
       prc out sys_refcursor
      )
      is
      ssql varchar2(32767);
```

I have created a method to call this stored procedure -

```
 SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withCatalogName("IIOWNER")
                .withProcedureName("GET_WISLA_REPORT")
                .declareParameters(
                        new SqlParameter("chkActiveWI", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("chkWILastYr", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("chkSLAMetPercentage", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("chkAvgCompletionTime", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("chkActiveWorkTypes", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlOutParameter("prc", OracleTypes.CURSOR)
                )
                .returningResultSet("prc", BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(WorkItemSLAReportDto.class));

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("chkActiveWI", workItemSLADto.getActiveWorkItem());
        ((MapSqlParameterSource) in).addValue("chkWILastYr", workItemSLADto.getWorkItem_DateRange());
        ((MapSqlParameterSource) in).addValue("chkSLAMetPercentage", workItemSLADto.getSLAPercentage());
        ((MapSqlParameterSource) in).addValue("chkAvgCompletionTime", workItemSLADto.getAvgCompletionTime());
        ((MapSqlParameterSource) in).addValue("chkActiveWorkTypes", workItemSLADto.getActiveWorktype());

        Map<String, Object> result =
                jdbcCall.execute(in);
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
        List<WorkItemSLAReportDto> workitemslareport =  (List) result.get("prc");
        System.out.println(workitemslareport.get(0).ActiveWorkItems);
        return workitemslareport;
```

But its giving me error as - wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_WISLA_REPORT'

Please help me in identifying the issue.

Comment: This isn't something I'm familiar with, so just a guess; is it appropriate to have `returningResultSet` for a procedure call? That sounds like something you'd only use for a function call.

Comment: okay.. I tried removing .returningresultset also.. still its giving me the same error

Comment: OK, then another guess but on *slightly* firmer ground; the argument names might need to be in uppercase in the `addValue` calls, as they aren't quoted identifiers in the procedure declaration?

Comment: No :( that also didnt work.

Comment: I meant to say in the `SqlParameter` (and `SqlOutParameter`) calls, as well as the `addValue` calls, but I assume you changed them consistently anyway or you'd have had other errors... did you try that change both with and without the `returningResultSet `? Anyway, I'm out of guesses, hopefully someone who knows what they're talking about will come along and be able to help you!